# how to test Routes in react using jest and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

so I'm trying to test each Route component and url are matching

*the function*

```
const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Layout>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
                    <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignupPage} />
                    <Route exact path='/recipes' component={RecipesPage} />
                    <Route exact path='/recipes/:id' component={RecipeDetailPage} />
                    <Route exact path='/reset_password' component={ResetPasswordPage} />
                    <Route exact path='/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token' component={ResetPasswordConfirmPage} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

anyone has an idea how can i test this?

Answer (score 2):

so after some trial and error I have managed to get the answer, this is the test that worked for me:

(i added a test-id to the homePage so i could know that this is the component that got rendered)

```
describe('App', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const renderWithRouter = (ui, { route = '/' } = {}) => {
            window.history.pushState({}, 'Test page', route);

            return render(ui, { wrapper: BrowserRouter });
        };
        renderWithRouter(<App />);
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        cleanup();
    });
    test('should render without crashing', () => {});
    test('should render home page', () => {
        const homePage = screen.getByText('homePage');
        expect(homePage).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi. I am using a react typescript app with react version ^17 and react-router v6 and getting Forbidden usage of `render` within a testing framework `beforeEach` setup